# Webpack multiple entry and output points

Tags: webpack, entry-point, multiple-entries

Can I have multiple entry points corresponding to multiple output points in webpack.js ?

E.g.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './pathA1/fileA1',
    output: {
        path: './pathA2',
        filename: 'fileA2'
    },
    entry: './pathB1/fileB1',
    output: {
        path: './pathB2',
        filename: 'fileB2'
    }
}
```

I'd like that the entry ./pathA1/fileA1 is copied to ./pathA2/fileA2, and the entry ./pathB1/fileB1 is copied to ./pathB2/fileB2.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass an object to the entry key then each key of the object is treated as a separate file and corresponding output file is created for that

```
{
entry: {
    a: "./a",
    b: "./b",
    c: ["./c", "./d"]
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "[name].entry.js"
}
```

Quoting it from the webpack site

> To use multiple entry points you can pass an object to the entry option. Each value is treated as an entry point and the key represents the name of the entry point.
>
> When using multiple entry points you must override the default output.filename option. Otherwise each entry point would write to the same output file. Use [name] to get the name of the entry point.

Comment: Yes, sure and thanks for the answer. However what if the entry points have nothing to do with each other and I cannot correlate them through this [name] variable ?

Comment: The name variable here is the key. So for "a" name will be a. If the entry point have nothing to do with each other u can use something like this 
output: {
      path: base.coreOutDir,
      filename: '[name]/[name].bundle.js'
    }
Doing this will create a file under a different folder name as the given key.